# Machine learning model predicting wrong results

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-extraction

Currently, I have a dataset which contains two columns procedure name and their CPTs. For example, Total Knee Arthroplasty-27447, Total Hip Arthroplasty -27130, Open Carpal Tunnel Release-64721. The dataset has 3000 rows and there are total 5 CPT codes(5 classes). I am writing a classification model.  When I am passing some wrong input, for example, "open knee arthroplasty carpal tunnel release", it is giving output 64721 which is wrong. Below is the code which I am using. May I know what changes I could make in my code and if choosing a Neural Network for this problem is correct?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

xl = pd.ExcelFile("dataset.xlsx") # reading the data
df = xl.parse('Query 2.2') 

# shuffling the data
df=df.sample(frac=1)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['procedure'], df['code'], random_state = 0,test_size=0.10)
count_vect = CountVectorizer().fit(X_train)
X_train_counts = count_vect.transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts) 
model= MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(25),max_iter=500)
classificationModel=model.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

data_to_be_predicted="open knee arthroplasty carpal tunnel release"

result = classificationModel.predict(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted]))
predictionProbablityMatrix = classificationModel.predict_proba(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted]))
maximumPredictedValue = np.amax(predictionProbablityMatrix)
if maximumPredictedValue * 100 > 99:
    print(result[0])
else:
    print("00000")
```

Comment: Yes you right, for example, when I am passing open knee arthroplasty carpal tunnel release, it should give  "00000", but it is giving "64721" which is wrong.

Comment: I did not get you, predictionProbablityMatrix = classificationModel.predict_proba(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted])) will give me an array contaning 5 values because I have 5 classes, I am then using  np.amax(predictionProbablityMatrix) to choose the class with highest probablity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recomend you to use Keras for this problem. All the treatment to the data you did using sklearn after splitting the trainning and testing data could be made with numpy to keras and would be more readable and less confusing to know what's going on. If they're all strings you should split the data by rows with internal python code like

```
row = data[i].split(',')
```

would have the three columns in the row splitted.
If you have 5 knew classes then I'd take all the classes and replace their names for numbers in the dataset. I've never used Sklearn to implement a neural network, but it seems you used 25 hidden NN layers, is that right? I don't think you would need this much as well... think 3 would do the job.

Sorry if I couldn't help you more precisely in your problem, but I think you can solve your problem easier if you redo it like I said... good luck, buddy!

edit: Maybe the problem isn't in the parsed dataset, but in the NN implementation, that's why I think Keras is more clear

Comment: Oh! I see.. then maybe you need more, because as I saw, the problem is not linear, then you should add more Hidden Layers... Maybe your NN isn't learning well... do you have any callback from the trainning status (accuracy and stuff)? you should have some to check it out!

Comment: So as you suggested, I studied and used Keras. Now when I am predicting, I am getting output as 1. Why is it so? Is it because I am using Sigmoid function?

I referred this link:  https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/

Comment: I'm not sure... it's a particular case to be studied... try using loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' instead of binary and in the last layer use softmax okay